# How do I prove that there is an invertible matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: This is the problem]
How do I prove that there is an invertible matrix $S$ such that $A_C = S^T A_BS$

I know that a matrix is invertible if its determinant is not $0$ and also if $AA^{-1} = I_n$, but other than that, I don't know how to continue the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For $V = \mathbb R^2$ with standard scalar product (better understanding): Let $B = [b_1,b_2]$ and $C = [c_1,c_2]$ (the basis vectors as columns). Then it is easily seen that $A_B = B^TB$ and $A_C = C^TC$. Now, as $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal C$ are bases, $B$ and $C$ are invertible matrices, and so are their transposes (row rank = column rank). So, there exists an invertible matrix $S$ such that $C^T = SB^T$. So, $A_C = C^TC = (SB^T)(BS^T) = S(B^TB)S^T = SA_BS^T$.

For $V\neq\mathbb R^2$ represent the vectors of $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal C$ with respect to an arbitrary orthonormal basis of $V$.