# How do I prove that B is orthonormal if and only if C is orthonormal?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: This is the problem]

[image: This is the problem]

I know that $Q^TQ$ = $QQ^T$ = $I$. Other than that, I don't know how to translate this property into a proof.

Comment: I don't see $Q$ in your task, so I am pretty confused what $Q$ stands for. Also please consider rewriting your task using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710748/how-do-i-prove-that-there-is-an-invertible-matrix